# IsCurrent Column In SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, calculated-columns

I have a schema similar to this:

```
ID     UserID      DateApplied     IsCurrent
1      1           2016-07-01      0
2      2           2016-07-05      0
3      1           2016-07-04      0
4      1           2016-07-10      1
5      2           2016-07-07      1
```

Is there a way to make the IsCurrent column a calculated column which is true for the maximum date for each user.

**Ie:** Each time the table is updated when a new record is added, the newest record will have the current (most recent) DateTime, which should make the IsCurrent column true.

Comment: try to use a trigger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a `View` and using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY`

```
SELECT
   Id,
   UserID,
   DateApplied,
   CASE WHEN x.RowNum = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsCurrent
FROM 
(
   SELECT
      RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY DateApplied DESC),
      Id,
      UserID,
      DateApplied
   FROM YourTable
) x
```

Comment: This led me to create a CTE which uses `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION` to return the right data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I was able to get this to work just now by using a Function.  It seems the Computed Column Specification can only reference the columns of that particular row, but you can call a method with those parameters.

So, what I did was define the function. For this case, it would be something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsCurrent (@UserID  int, @DateApplied int) 
    RETURNS BIT AS 
    BEGIN   

        DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME;  
        DECLARE @IsCurrent bit;     

        SET @MaxDate = (SELECT MAX(DateApplied)
                        FROM MyTable 
                        WHERE MyTable.UserID = @UserID)         

        IF (@MaxDate = @DateApplied)        
            SET @IsCurrent = 1;     
        ELSE
            SET @IsCurrent = 0;

        RETURN @IsCurrent; 
    END 
GO
```

Then your Computed Column Specification would be:

```
dbo.IsCurrent(UserID, DateApplied)
```

Beware that this could  [impact performance if you have a lot of inserts.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2011/11/28/a-computed-column-defined-with-a-user-defined-function-might-impact-query-performance/)

Comment: This seems like a sound approach but I couldn't get it to work, so I used a CTE instead.